# Vim - Eclim for PHP

Tags: php, vim, eclim

I am using Manjaro Linux (based on Arch Linux). I instaled Eclipse and then Eclim (both from AUR). First time it was working, but I was able to create only C++ project. Then, I tried to install Eclipse PHP (also from AUR), but then Eclim stopped working. After that I was completely unable to start Eclim daemon. Can you help me what to install to be able to create PHP project.

I also posted this on Google Groups for Eclim, but there seems to be almost no activity.

Comment: Can you provide more infos how are you unable to start eclim daemon? Any error messages, any logs?

Comment: Tried to reproduce the error and came to the solution. Thanks for your time!

Comment: That's good, please share what solved your problem by answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem is to install the Eclim from their website, not the one from the AUR. During the installation, there is option to choose specific programming languages.